# equivalent docker run command for working docker-compose (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

If have a docker-compose file for postgres that works as expected and I'm able to access it from R. See relevant content below. However, I also need an equivalent "docker run" command but for some reason cannot get this to work. As far as I can tell the commands / setup are equivalent. Any suggestions?

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - ~/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The docker run command I'm using is:

```
    docker run -p 5432:5432 \
      --name postgres \
      -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
      -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
      -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data \
      -v ~/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
      -d postgres
```

EDIT 1: In both settings I'm trying to connect from another docker container/service. In the docker-compose setting the different services are described in one and the same yml file

EDIT 2: David's answer provided all the information I needed. Create a docker network and reference that network in each `docker run` call. For those interested in a shell script that uses this setup to connect postgres, pgadmin4, and a data science container with R and Python see the link below:

https://github.com/radiant-rstats/docker/blob/master/launch-rsm-msba-pg.sh

Comment: Your container is running, you have supplied the `-d` (detach) flag. You can check it by running `docker container ls`.

Comment: Using `--rm` gives the same result (i.e., can't connect). Somehow there is a difference between what the `docker-compose` setup is doing and what the `docker run` setup is doing.

Comment: If you connect to the database from another docker container, use the service name in the connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Compose will [automatically create a Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you (per Compose file).  For inter-container DNS to work, [you can't use the default Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) but any named network will work.  So you need to add that bit of setup:

```sh
docker network create some-name  # default options are fine
docker run --net some-name --name postgres ...
  # will be accessible as "postgres" from other containers on
  # the "some-name" network
```